# iframe - set Content Type header

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7, base64

I would like to display a JPEG image dynamically using iframe, but its header should be `"Content-type: image/jpeg"`.

Is this possible?

This would be a workaround for displaying base64 images in IE7:

1) get base 64 code

2) decode it using js

3) generate iframe image

Comment: Are you retrieving the base64 image from other website?

Comment: @Jay No. But I dont want to send a request to my site to decode base64.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I did not get what you actually need (especially decode it using js part) but you can try some thing like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AFefT/2/)

```
    var data64 = "your encoded staf..."
    document.getElementById("divContent").innerHTML = "<iframe name='innerFrame' src='"+data64 +"'></iframe>";
```

Apparently the above code doesn t work for IE. you can use the below block instead.

```
    var data64 = "your encoded staf..."
    document.getElementById("divContent").innerHTML = "<iframe name='innerFrame'></iframe>";
    var objDoc = window.frames[ "innerFrame" ].document;
    objDoc.write("<img src='"+data64 +"' />");
```

you can also add an image to iframe document. But I would just use the adding a img tag to original page (parent page of the iframe.)

Comment: IE7,8 does not support base64 "stuff"

Answer (score -1):

You'd want to return the content-type from the server returning the iframe source.

In other words if your iframe looked like: `<iframe src="http://www.foobar.com/test.php>`, the `test.php` should set the content-type to `image/jpeg`

Comment: I need some javascript code that says to IE: the content of the iframe is not plain text but jpeg source

Comment: Regardless of the Content-type header, browsers seem to always change it to HTML content.  You can verify by using an inspector in developer tools.